# Understanding jacoco report

Tags: jenkins-plugins, jacoco

This is a sample jacoco report for a class. I want to understand what these column values mean and what does M and C in each column mean?
Also, which is the appropriate column to check the right coverage for a given class and its methods. Should I go with instruction or line coverage?
What is the ideal coverage percentage for a class?

---

Name      instruction      branch       complexity         line           method

---

constructor_name M:0 C:4 (100%) M:0 C:0 0%  M:0 C:1 100%   M:0 C:2 100%  M:0 C:1 100%
method_name M:0 C:52 (100%) M:0 C:2 100%  M:0 C:2 100%   M:0 C:9 100%  M:0 C:1 100%

Note: I could not upload image as I didn't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 3):

As you can see in the following image:

[image]

You have: Coverage, Covered Lines, Missed Lines and Total Lines.

I'll suggest you to use the eclipse plugin for the visualization of the jacoco report.

Hope it helps!